# Attaching event to dynamic inserted button on page with jquery using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamically-generated

I have a page where I return users posts, these posts can be commented on the fly using some jquery code, after a new comment is posted I insert the new comment under the post along with a `Delete` button. The problem is the `Delete` button doesn't work on the newly inserted element unless I reload the page. I read that the solution is using the .on() method however I am a little confused re how to implement this.
I have one function that updates the post part with the newly inserted comment and this is the function that deletes the comment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button[id*='deletecmnt_']").click(function () {

        var id = this.id.replace('deletecmnt_', '');

        var comment_card_id = ('#comment_' + id);

        var token = $(this).data('token');

        $.ajax({
            url: '../comment/' + id,
            type: 'post',
            data: {_method: 'delete', _token: token},
            success: function () {


                // Checks for display of comment card and removes it
                if ($(comment_card_id).is(":visible")) {

                    $(comment_card_id).fadeOut("fast");

                }
            }
        })

    })

});
```

I don't understand what needs to be changed here and how.

Comment: is it possible to reduce the code to the bare minimum. It's a lot right now to go through

Comment: please wait, I'll try

Comment: I also suggest to put `console.log("<INSERT_PLACE> called")` at key points to see if certain points of the code are not called. It's quite useful to find problems.

Comment: that's a good edit @Chriz74, keep that in mind for other questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for elements added dynamically. In your .on() method, you need to add the selector that you want the handler attached to after it's created.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("body").on("click", "button[id*='deletecmnt_']", function () {
    // codes
    }
 });
```

This will listen for clicks on elements not yet created that match your selector. Here's the JQuery API doc page for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: what happens to the $(document).ready(function () part of my code? Do I have to remove it or it doesn't matter?

Comment: `$(document).ready(...)` is necessary, otherwise it's possible that handlers on `body` or other elements of the **DOM** will not exist when you'll declare them.

Comment: glad I could help. please remember to accept the answer.